# On OS X, using VirtualBox's Command Line Interface, how can I instruct a VM to open a URL in a web browser?

Tags: virtualbox

From Terminal in Mac OS X, I want to use VBoxManage guestcontrol to control Windows XP in a VirtualBox Virtual Machine, to open a URL in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Steps

1. Start the VM: `VBoxManage startvm "{VM NAME}" --type headless`
2. Open the URL: `VBoxmanage guestcontrol "{VM NAME}" exec "{SHORT PATH TO THE BROWSER}" --username "{USER NAME}" --password "{PASSWORD}" "{URL TO OPEN}"`.

#### Headless

The `--type headless` option is optional, if you want to see what's happening you can omit this.

#### Getting the short name

An easy way to get the short path to the browser is to open cmd.exe and run; 
`cd "{NORMAL LONG PATH TO BROWSER}"` then `command` and the short path name will be displayed.

#### Params

- {VM NAME} == Case sensitive name of the virtual machine.
- {USER NAME} == System User name on the guest running on the VM, not the displayed name.
- {PASSWORD} == Password for the above account
- {URL TO OPEN} == eg: https://stackoverflow.com/
- {SHORT PATH TO THE BROWSER} == eg: C:\DOCUME~1\JAMIE~1\LOCALS~1\APPLIC~1\GOOGLE\CHROME\APPLIC~1\chrome.exe

#### Example

To open IE9 from the VM available from https://github.com/xdissent/ievms

```
VBoxmanage guestcontrol 'IE9 - Win7' exec 'C:\Progra~1\Intern~1\iexplore.exe' --username 'IEUser' --password 'Passw0rd!' 'http://google.com'
```

#### Credit

Thanks to http://www.quora.com/Chapley-Watson for this answer, I'd searched all over the place including Stack Overflow and got no replies. Hopefully this will help someone.

Comment: I'm trying to create an .app launcher I can stick in my dock for the startvm command, I thought I could put the line 1. in a shell script and then use platypus to create the launcher, but when I try and run it it says "cannot execute binary file" - any ideas?

Comment: You could create a regular bash script and save it as a .command file - they can go on your dock and be run kind of like apps

Answer (score 1):

## Completing fold_left answer for new version of VBox 5.0.2

With new version they have changed some commands. The process will be as follows:

### Steps:

1. Start the VM: `VBoxManage startvm "{VM NAME}" --type headless` (no changes)
2. Open the URL: `VBoxmanage guestcontrol "{VM NAME}" start --exe "{SHORT PATH TO THE BROWSER}" --username "{USER NAME}" --password "{PASSWORD}" -- iexplore "{URL TO OPEN}"`. (**new commands**)

### Example

To open IE9 from the VM available from https://github.com/xdissent/ievms

`VBoxmanage guestcontrol 'IE9 - Win7' start --exe 'C:\Progra~1\Intern~1\iexplore.exe' --username 'IEUser' --password 'Passw0rd!' -- iexplore 'http://www.wikipedia.org'`